# C++ and EXE won't run

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following C++ code: I am trying to understand why the code is compiling fine but it won't run in the exe, and I am trying to get an output file out of the result any clues to why this ight be happening? The error it mentions is ios::base something.

## Edit1

This was the error,  `` undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()' `` that I had at first running the program in the following method:

```
g++ -o plot1 Derivative.cpp
```

### Edit

I fixed my code and the code takes the derivative of a function as desired and returns the result into a dat file.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
float function(float j);
int main(){
    const double a =.0001;
    int i = 0;
    string filename;
    double x[100], delta[100], deltax[100],dx1[100],y_1[100],y_0[100],derivative_f[100];
    ofstream myfile;
    cin >> filename;
    myfile.open (filename, ios::out | ios::trunc );
    for(int i = 1; i < 101; i++)    {

         x[i]= i*.2;
         delta[i] = {a * x[i]};
         deltax[i] = {x[i]+delta[i]};
         dx1[i] = {deltax[i]-x[i]};
         y_1[i] = {function(deltax[i])};
         y_0[i] = {function(x[i])};
         derivative_f[i] = {(y_1[i]-y_0[i])/dx1[i]};
         myfile << x[i] << ' ' << derivative_f[i] << endl; 
    } 
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
float function(float j){
    float result;
    result = exp(j);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What exactly does "won't run" mean? Do you get any errors?

Comment: "The error it mentions is ios::base something." We need the actual error, not just a partial paraphrase of the error. As is, the error is likely the out of bounds access I mentioned, but you need to provide the *actual* error as part of a [MCVE], not just a paraphrase of a tiny bit of it.

Comment: run it under your debugger, it will point you right at the issue

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I got IOS but the person who answered got it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Theres the error you were asking for.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Theres the error you were asking for.

Answer (score 3):

This is your first problem:

```
for (int i = 0; 100; i++){
```

Note your condition, `100`. That's an infinite loop, because you didn't test it, and `100` is "true". Try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
```

Your second loop has the same problem. In practice, neither loop is likely to be infinite, since your program will eventually crash as it tries to read/write unallocated memory.

Comment: Thanks +1 @ShadowRanger

Comment: @JoseSerra: You've definitely got some math errors, e.g. your computation of `dx` is almost certainly wrong, since you use `int`s, so the result is `0`, not a fractional quantity. But that's unrelated to your program crashing.

Comment: @MooingDuck: The arrays are initialized before being used. Just because they're not initialized up front doesn't mean they're used uninitialized.